# Let $f,g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. Show that the topology induced by $(f,g)$ fromtopology $\tau'$ of half open intervals $[a,b)$ to $\Bbb R$ is discrete.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f,g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, be the maps $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$. Show that the topology  induced by the pair $(f,g)$ from the topology $\tau'$ of half open intervals $[a,b)$ to $\Bbb R$ is discrete.

Let $\mathcal{A}_f = \{f^{-1}(V) \mid V \in \tau' \}$ and $\mathcal{A}_g =\{g^{-1}(U) \mid U \in \tau' \}$. Then $\mathcal{A}_f$ and $\mathcal{A}_g$ are both subbases for the induced topology $\tau$.

Now $$\mathcal{A}_f=\{\{x \in \Bbb R \mid x \in [a,b)\} \mid [a,b) \in \tau' \} \\ \mathcal{A}_g=\{\{x \in \Bbb R \mid -x \in [c,d) \} \mid [c,d) \in \tau'\}$$

but $\mathcal{A}_g$ can be written as $$\mathcal{A}_g=\{\{x \in \Bbb R \mid x\in (-d,-c] \} \mid [c,d) \in \tau'\}$$

Now let $\mathcal{A}= \mathcal{A}_f \cup \mathcal{A}_g$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a subbase for the induced topology also and we can get a basis for the induced topology by taking finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

These intersections are of form $[a,b)$, $(-d,-c], \emptyset$ and $[a, -c]$. Neither of which are singletons. I think we can get the singletons whenever $a = -c$, then $[a,-c]=\{a\}$, but is this enough to show that we induce the discrete topology?

Comment: “$A_f$ and $A_g$ are both sub bases…” seems wrong. They determine different topologies, so they can’t be subbasis of the same topology. However $A_f\cup A_g$ is a subbasis.

Comment: The key is really that if $x\in\mathbb R$ then $(x-1,x]=g^{-1}([-x,1-x))\in A_g$ and $[x,x+1)=f^{-1}([x,x+1))\in A_f,$ and $\{x\}=(x-1,x]\cap [x,x+1).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have proved that every singleton belongs to your topology. That's enough: if every singleton belongs to a topology on $\Bbb R$, then every subset $C$ of $\Bbb R$ belongs to it too, since $C=\bigcup_{c\in C}\{c\}$. So, the topology is the discrete topology.